# RestFB - I can only get 5 friends from friend list

Tags: restfb

This is my code:

```
Connection<User> myFriends = fb.fetchConnection("me/friends", User.class);
myFriends.getData();  //List size just = 5
myFriends.getTotalCount(); // this method return 52 (I have 52 friends).
```

I dont know how to get enough 52 friends. Thank for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I'd like to quote the graph api reference as answer ;)

> This edge allows you to:
>
> - get the User's friends who have installed the app making the query
> - get the User's total number of friends (including those who have not installed the app making the query)

So 5 friends are using the app and you have 52 in total.

See here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/user/friends/